# 403 while accessing webpage using apache

Tags: apache, web-applications, apache2, httpforbiddenhandler

I set up apache and changed my home directory to my 
`desktop/project`.

I created a webpage and when I try to open it with `http:// localhost/app/index.html`, and the website works properly without any problem. But when I give the link as `http:// 127.0.0.1/app/index.html`  I get a error 403 Forbidden.

Thanks in advance. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: There is only one page which is index.html in my project and let me know what changes I have to make.

Comment: am not using spring security. Where will the web.xml be located?